# Opening file in new tab shows blank page in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to open file in new tab, here is my controller.js

```
leadsService.getLeadFileContent(item.upload_name, function (data) {
        var url = "" + data;
        var type = '';
        if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('.png')) {
            type = 'image/png';
        }
        else if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('.pdf')) {
            type = 'application/pdf';
        }
        else if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('.doc')) {
            type = 'application/msword';
        }
        else if (item.name.toLowerCase().indexOf('.txt')) {
            type = 'application/txt';
        }
        else if (fileName.toLowerCase().indexOf('.xls')) {
            type = 'application/xls';
        }
        var newTab = $window.open('about:blank', '_blank');
        newTab.document.write("<object width='400' height='400' data='" + url + "' type='" + type + "' ></object>");
    });
```

but the new tab opened is blank,it didn't show anything.
what should I suppose to do?

Comment: Can you just do `window.open(url, '_blank')`? If not, perhaps you should make a specific page that takes `url` as a GET parameter then injects it into an `<object>` tag.

Comment: The big question is, are you sure that there is a file there that matches what this function is trying to show?

Comment: @Mike C, Yup its still opens new empty tab.

Comment: Open your console (hit F12) on the new tab. Do you see any errors such as a 404?

Comment: @Mike C yup it shows 404 error.

Comment: @NomanAhmad That means that the url is invalid. Your code is working fine otherwise.